# How does function work regarding to the memory usage?

Tags: matlab, function, memory

When you are using `function` in MATLAB you have just the output of the function in the work space and all the other variables that maybe created or used in the body of that function are not shown. I am wondering how does `function` work? Does it clear all other variables from memory and just save the output?

Comment: It's fundamentally the same mechanism as in many other programming languages. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack.

Answer (score 1):

[`function`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html) acts like a small, isolated programming environment. At the front end you insert your input (e.g. variables, strings, name-value pairs etc). After the function has finished, only the output is available, discarding all temporarily created variables.

```
function [SUM] = MySum(A)
    for ii = 1:length(A)-1
        SUM(ii) = A(ii)+A(ii+1);
        kk(ii) = ii;
    end
end

>> A=1:10
>> MySum(A)
```

This code just adds two consecutive values for the input array `A`. Note that the iteration number, stored in `kk`, is not output and is thus discarded after the function has completed. In MATLAB `kk(ii) = ii;` will be underlined orange, since it 'might be unused'.

Say you want to also retain `kk`, just add it to the function outputs:

```
function [SUM,kk] = MySum(A)
```

and keep the rest the same.

If you have large variables that you only use up to a certain point and wish them not clogging up your memory whilst the function is running, use `clear` for that:

```
function [SUM] = MySum(A)
    for ii = 1:length(A)-1
        SUM(ii) = A(ii)+A(ii+1);
        kk(ii) = ii;
    end
clear kk
end
```

Comment: I know it just give me the output, but does it keep other variables in my memory or RAM?

Comment: That's what I explained there: `kk` is discarded, so it does not keep it anywhere. (Besides memory = RAM (Random Access Memory)) You will not be able to access `kk` after the function has completed.

Comment: So all the variables are in the RAM but only the output is accessible. using the `clear` can I delete them from RAM?

Comment: They are in the RAM *as long as the function is running*. After exiting the function, MATLAB automatically clears them. You can use `clear` in the function itself if you're short on memory.